# change layout form when i click one radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, radio-button

Hello I am a student and recently I am learning JavaScript, CSS, and HTML and in making an exercise I have a problem.
In exercise, I'm using Bootstrap.

```js
function Form(stringa){
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById(stringa).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Form di registrazione</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
     <h1>Form di Registrazione</h1>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value=1 onclick="Form('form1');" >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Privato</label>
      </div>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" onclick="Form('form2'); " value=2>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Azienda</label>
      </div>
      <form id="form1" class="row g-3" value=1>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
        </div>
    </form>

    <form id="form2" type="hidden"class="row g-3"style="display:none;" value=2>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Eeeeee</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why when I click on the radio button it changes the form layout?
Thank you, everyone

Comment: Most likely, the layout is changing due to JavaScript OnClick event `onclick="Form('form1');` - This event hides `form2` and add css display block to `form1` (which is probably the causes). Theres not enough code to provide a solution. It's possible you can fix this by replacing block with an empty string. Anyway what is the purpose of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll already have 2 different forms.
On click at radio input (which placed outside the forms? what?) will run function with toggle forms display.

**What's happened:** Hiding one of form and showing another one with different numbers of inputs.